# R: How to pass array in the POST request with form encoding?

Tags: r, post, shiny, httr

The post request looks like this :
curl --location --request POST '' 
--form 'ids=["ae8a1312","59569d79"]'

Here the ids need to be passed as an array in the post request. Tried using the following code:

```
body <- list(
        sweep_ids = ids
      )
resp <- POST(url, body = body, encode = "form")
```

Here variable `ids` is the list of ids. The above piece of code gives the following error

```
Warning: Error in vapply: values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2
```

Can't use encoding as JSON.

How can I pass the list of ids to this form-encoded POST request in R?

Comment: Try `POST(url, body = '{"a":"ae8a1312","b":"59569d79"}', encode = "raw")`. Still not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
    l <- paste('["',paste(ids, collapse='","' ),'"]', sep="")

    body <- list(
        sweep_ids = l
      )

   resp <- POST(url, body = body, encode = "form")
```

Collapse the list as text